# Is it possible to collapse a text using HTML only?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in HTML only? I saw with CSS but my environment doesn't cater CSS. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: @vina chan it is possible using css please go through the link: https://codepen.io/Idered/pen/AeBgF

Comment: Hi, is it possible to not set where you will cut the text?

Comment: For example, The "Read more" button in YouTube only shows when the text exceeds 4 lines. I want something like that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using the [HTML Details Element `<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details):

```html
<details>
    <summary>Summary</summary>

    <p>Detailed content goes here …</p>
</details>
```

Check [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=details).

Comment: Yes but it is possible to not set what you put in Summary and content? For example: "I have a long text"

I want to achieve:

"I have a"

then if you click it, it will collapse like:

"I have a
long text"

Something like that.

Comment: @VinaChan No, that’s not possible with only HTML. You have to set the content manually.

Comment: If so, do you know how to do it?

Comment: @VinaChan Sorry, I don't understand your last question.

Comment: Hi, what I mean is if you have a certain text. And you will limit this to 30 characters only. If it exceeds, then it will expand at the bottom part.

Comment: You're going to need JavaScript for that. Or you could prepare the truncated values on the server side. @VinaChan

Comment: Hi, I have here my code. Do you know how I can remove the "Show more or Show Less" so that i can click the whole div and collapse it?

http://jsfiddle.net/7Vv8u/2703/